# How do I give one stylesheet precedence over the other with Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, sprockets

I've been looking all over the place and I can't figure out how to give one stylesheet precedence over another. This is what I have in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

/* Master Reset */
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

I also have a file in the same directory called `welcome.scss` for my controller whose name is `welcome`:

```
// Place all the styles related to the welcome controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/

body {
  background-color: orange;
}

h4 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

I'd expect that I could overwrite the CSS of `application.css` with the content output by `welcome.scss`, but my HTML output has them in the following order:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/welcome.self-6767494a578e8cc2f59dd92fa7081a577973e0fdcd72f58e91863e405fcf1e4d.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-8e112c6b70d20efd74388d7b26053c97e2b11700f8ef5d5b5f9d723770f2e869.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
```

This means `application.css` is overwriting the orange `background-color` from `welcome.scss` which I'd wanted to overwrite it. I've tried moving the `require` directives in `application.css` around to the bottom and all kinds of stuff (I'd thought I wasn't writing them correctly). I've moved them back to the place they were in the beginning. How can I include `welcome.scss` *after* `application.css`?

Yes, I am a Rails noob. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally do not want to include CSS in `application.css` and instead use this just for directives.  If you do include CSS there, Rails will include it after all directives, regardless of where you put it in the file, hence your problem.

I believe you can use directive `require_self` to override this and specify the order that CSS from the directive file gets included.  You can look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) for more information.

Comment: I've reversed the `*=require` directives at the top, so what's so bad about putting CSS in `application.css`? It seems that would make the most sense because it will be the first file, now. I can put my structure things and my reset in it so it will be included in all pages.

Comment: See my update - if you start your directives with `require_self`, the CSS in your directive file will come first (which is what you want).

Comment: Thanks, lovely! I'll mark this as the answer in a few minutes (when I'm allowed to.)

Comment: Glad to help.  Maybe it is just a matter of style or preference, but I like manifest files to just have directives and not content.  Fine as long as you keep everything straight I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

The following will place *application.css* onto the top:

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```